# Dismiss keyboard for textfield in uitableviewcell in tableviewcontroller - Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a textfield and textview in my custom tableviewcell.

I have 4 different prototype cell with 4 different class created. there is a textfield in 1 prototype cell and a textview in the other.

I am not sure how I can do it and I dont understand the obj-c answers out there.

I've tried

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tap: UIGestureRecognizer = UIGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIInputViewController.dismissKeyboard))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap) }
```

and

```
func dismissKeyboard() {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

I wanted to try

`UITextFieldDelegate` and `touchesbegan` and `textfieldshouldreturn` method, but there are no textfields to call in my tableviewcontroller.

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what you're attempting to do here?

Comment: I wanted to find anyway of dismissing the keyboard, seems like i missed out setting keyboard to dismiss interactively in storyboard! however, it does not dismiss the keyboard with 'return' key

Comment: In that case, you'll want to use @rMickeyD's answer in each of your `UITableViewCell` classes that contain a `UITextField` or `UITextView`.

Answer (score 1):

Go to attributes inspector in storyboard and click tableView and set keyboard to dismiss interactively.

Or

Set textField delegate and implement

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    textField.delegate = self
 }

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool // called when 'return' key pressed. return false to ignore.
{
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

Comment: the first method works! but for the second, i do not have any textfield to input in `viewDidLoad`. my textfields are in the `tableviewcell`'s class

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, you can solve this with IQKeyboardManager, you don't need to complicate things with the custom cell classes, just install it on your project, when you're all set with installation, in the appDelegate inside the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method, add this line of code:

```swift
IQKeyboardManager.shared.shouldResignOnTouchOutside = true
```

Get IQKeyboardManager from [here](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager).